# initialization corresponding class by call class before defined in c++

Tags: c++, class

I'm first time at c++ and I tried to find my question but I cannot find good answer.. so can you help me?
So my question is how to use class before define

What I have learn by searching & book
1. I can declare just class name and can use it
2. I better use pointer at not defined class

this code is convertable corresponding point of coordinate system between RectangularPoint and PolarPoint
I got error on correspondingRP

```
class RectangularPoint; // predefine

class PolarPoint
{
public:
    double degree;
    double radialDistance;

public:
    PolarPoint():degree(0), radialDistance(0), correspondingRP_Defined(false), correspondingRP(new RectangularPoint()) {} // <--error
    PolarPoint(double _degree, double _radialDistance):
            degree(_degree),
            radialDistance(_radialDistance),
            correspondingRP_Defined(false),
            correspondingRP(new RectangularPoint()){} // <--error

public:
    void SetInfo(double _degree, double _radialDistance);
    RectangularPoint* toRectangular();

private:
    RectangularPoint *correspondingRP; // used pointer
    bool correspondingRP_Defined;
};


class RectangularPoint
{
public:
    double x;
    double y;

public:
    RectangularPoint(): x(0), y(0), correspondingRP_Defined(false), correspondingPP(new PolarPoint()) {}
    RectangularPoint(double x, double y): x(x), y(y), correspondingRP_Defined(false), correspondingPP(new PolarPoint()) {}

public:
    void SetInfo(double x, double y);
    PolarPoint* toPolar();

private:
    PolarPoint *correspondingPP;
    bool correspondingRP_Defined;
};

PolarPoint* RectangularPoint::toPolar() {
        if (correspondingRP_Defined) {
        return correspondingPP;
    } else {
        ...
        return correspondingPP;
    }
}

RectangularPoint* PolarPoint::toRectangular() {
    if (correspondingRP_Defined) {
        return correspondingRP;
    } else {
        ...
        return correspondingRP;
    }
}
```

I got error on correspondingRP

```
error: invalid use of incomplete type 'class RectangularPoint'
```

what is good way to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, so you'll have to split that constructor up into a declaration:

```
PolarPoint(double _degree, double _radialDistance);
```

and a later definition (outside of the class definition):

```
PolarPoint::PolarPoint(double _degree, double _radialDistance)
   : degree(_degree)
   , radialDistance(_radialDistance)
   , correspondingRP_Defined(false)
   , correspondingRP(new RectangularPoint())
{}
```

Your book should have an example (and explanation) of this too.

While this is a reasonably common problem, if you can eliminate the circular "reference" completely (by re-addressing your design) then so much the better.